# Book with a flying wooden ship on the cover

Tags: story-identification, books

So I saw a book years and years ago and it had a flying ship on the cover, like a normal wooden ship with a giant sail. I can't fully remember the plot, but I remember the main character and his dad (I think) going to this meeting thing and fangirling over all the ships, their captain and crew, as well as their weapons and tools. I remember one being called the 'Flying Dutchman.'

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year (or range of years) did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: https://patricktreardon.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Cooper.CloudWalker-640x1024.jpg

Comment: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/417MIKDBw9L._SX333_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg

Comment: Could the ships actually fly?

Comment: https://www.risingshadow.net/libdb_images/books/34757-to-sail-the-century-sea.jpg

Comment: TSR Spelljammer books?

Comment: Was the ship flying in space or in the sky?

Comment: [The Edge Chronicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Edge_Chronicles)?